# class attribute is not working in select option javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html(`index.html`) and a javascript(`controller.js`) file. There is a `<div>` in `index.html`

```
<div id="tableContent"></div>
```

I am sending a table to that div from `controller.js`.

```
var table = "<table border='1' class='table table-bordered TextHighlight'>"+
                "<tr><th>Your Score</th></tr>"+
                "<tr><td id='score1'><select id='partner_SC1' class='playautofirst_withpartner' name='partner_SC1'><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></td></tr>"+
             "</table>";

$("#tableContent").html(table);

$(".playautofirst_withpartner").change(function(){
   alert('working'); 
});
```

Table is showing properly in `index.html`. But when i change select dropdown value `no alert is showing`. I want to do some calculation when select option value changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change**

```
$(".playautofirst_withpartner").change(function(){
```

**TO**

```
$(document).on('change','.playautofirst_withpartner',function(){
```

You need to use event delegation for `DOM` which are added later.

Comment: This may be the solution, but to a problem the OP didn't properly described (because the code in the question does work if ran in that exact order). There must be something async the question isn't mentioning.

Comment: @bfavaretto if OP missing `document.ready` then `html` won't be added on page...so its easy for me to understand what was the actual problem....now you can see OP comment that was the solution.

Comment: I understand this was the solution, but I don't think the problem was a missing document.ready. If this was loaded before the div existed, the table wouldn't even show.